# Best practice spring mvc & hibernate approach for delete a record, pass model or parameter is better?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm new to Java and also spring and hibernate.
This is my current order of layers: views -> controllers -> services -> DAO -> DB.

I want to delete a record. I recieved id in my controller from view. Now I want to know that which one is best practice: send id to service and delegate to DAO layer and do the delete by query, or retrieve the model in controller and pass the model to service layer and DAO and delete that model?

I know that the second approach will execute 2 queries. But in other perspective I know that we should pass models through layers, not parameteres.

Answer (score 0):

> But in other perspective I know that we should pass models through layers, not parameteres.

That would be highly inconvenient in some of the cases. The most trivial one being requesting information about some object while knowing only it's ID or some other property. You ask your service about object detail while giving this information.

The same goes for deleting. You send ID of object you wish to delete into the service and inside you are handling the deletion. So all is OK with the single query approach.